# split a line separated by space into an associative array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dictionary, awk

if i have a variable with data as below:

```
Audit 9201 Management 9202 Inventory 9203 Source 9204 Flemingo 9205
```

i'm trying to convert my $var into an expected associative array as below.

```
var="Audit 9201 Management 9202 Inventory 9203 Source 9204 Flemingo 9205"
declare -A varMap
$ varMap[Audit]=9201
$ varMap[Management]=9202
$ varMap[Inventory]=9203
$ varMap[Source]=9204
$ varMap[Flemingo]=9205
```

is there any efficient way to turn above variable $var into an associative array so that i can perform lookup based on key in my remaining piece of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, simple, readable and efficient :)

```
# declare a simple string
var='Audit 9201 Management 9202 Inventory 9203 Source 9204 Flemingo 9205'

# declare a simple array, using word spliting
arr=( $var )

# declare an associative array
declare -A varmap

# iterating over array to feed varmap associative array
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=2)) {
    varmap[${arr[i]}]=${arr[i+1]}
}  

# new request from comments: the max value with key ending with `Management` :
for i in ${!varmap[@]}; do
    if [[ $i == *Management ]]; then
        if ((varmap[$i] > max)); then
            max=${varmap[$i]}
            var=$i
        fi
    fi
done

# test of one of a key
echo ${varmap[Management]}
```

### Output

```
9202
```

Comment: Thank you. i tested this.its working without issues.

Comment: This is the simplest solution ;) (with oguz ismail's one)

Comment: echo ${varMap[@]} | awk -v RS=" " '1' | sort -r | head -1 this is giving me max value from the associative array. is there a way, i can get max value for keys that has key ends with word "Managment" ? for example "AuditManagement".

Comment: yeah i did managed to figure out the above solution but yours is good compared to me.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. This will create dynamic automated script which will have automated array creation and will print its keys and values too. (these are test samples provided by OP itself in post)

```
var="Audit 9201 Management 9202 Inventory 9203 Source 9204 Flemingo 9205"
echo "$var" | 
awk -v s1="\"" -v array_name="arrvar" '
BEGIN{
  print "declare -A " array_name
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){
    print array_name "["$i"]="$(i+1)
  }
}
END{
  print "echo keys, values here for array.." ORS \
  "for key in " s1 "${!"array_name"[@]}" s1 "; do echo " s1 "$key => ${"array_name"[$key]}" s1 "; done"
}
' > file.ksh;chmod 755 file.ksh;./file.ksh
```

Following shell script will be created by above command:

```
cat file.ksh
declare -A arrvar
arrvar[Audit]=9201
arrvar[Management]=9202
arrvar[Inventory]=9203
arrvar[Source]=9204
arrvar[Flemingo]=9205
echo keys, values here for array..
for key in "${!arrvar[@]}"; do echo "$key => ${arrvar[$key]}"; done
```

When we run script it will give following output:

```
keys, values here for array..
Audit => 9201
Flemingo => 9205
Management => 9202
Source => 9204
Inventory => 9203
```

***Logical explanation:***

- Create/define a shell variable (in this case it is `var`).
- We can provide array named (`vararr` in this example).
- This will create a script named `file.ksh` which you can change it as per your wish.
- What `awk` code is doing, it is reading `var`(shell variable) then its printing command to create associative array named provided by you. It is also printing keys and values of that array. NOTE: it is writing only commands to do so NOT executing them as of now.
- Its saving output into a script file, named `file.ksh`(you can keep any name you need).
- Now permissions are given to `file.ksh` and running it, which will actually create an array named provided by you and print its values with indexes too.

Comment: Thank you. i tested this.its working without issues.great explanation to help others too.

Comment: @RavindraSingh:  can i add a condition to this awk to look for keys that end with "Management" word ?  below one giving me max value out of all keys. echo ${varMap[@]} | awk -v RS=" " '1' | sort -r | head -1

Comment: @ramesh.metta Could you please post a new question with samples and lemme know link of it we could discuss it there, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
while test "$var"; do
    read -r key value var <<<"$var"
    varMap[$key]=$value
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

```
var="Audit 9201 Management 9202 Inventory 9203 Source 9204 Flemingo 9205"
declare -A varMap="($(sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]\+\)[[:blank:]]\+\([^[:blank:]]\+\)/\[\1]=\2/g' <<< "$var"))"

# test
for i in "${!varMap[@]}"; do
    echo "$i => ${varMap[$i]}"
done
```

Result:

```
Audit => 9201
Flemingo => 9205
Management => 9202
Source => 9204
Inventory => 9203
```

Comment: Thank you. simple and clear to understand and try few more samples.